# Can't compile project with ffmpeg-light

Tags: haskell, ffmpeg

Compilation of any project which uses [openFile](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ffmpeg-light-0.11.1/docs/Codec-FFmpeg-Decode.html#v:openFile) function from [Codec.FFmpeg.Decode](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ffmpeg-light-0.11.1/docs/Codec-FFmpeg-Decode.html#) fails with error:

`Couldn't match type ‘GHC.IO.Exception.IOException’ with ‘[Char]’
            arising from a functional dependency between:
              constraint ‘mtl-2.2.1:Control.Monad.Error.Class.MonadError
                            String IO’
                arising from a use of ‘openFile’
              instance ‘mtl-2.2.1:Control.Monad.Error.Class.MonadError
                          GHC.IO.Exception.IOException IO’
                at <no location info>`

As an example, compilation of this fails:

```
openVideoFile :: String -> IO ()
openVideoFile filePath = do

  initFFmpeg

  avFmtCtx <- openFile filePath

  return ()
```

I guess the reason is that there is no ready instance of `MonadError String IO`. But, when I add a dummy instance like this:

```
instance MonadError String IO where
  throwError _   = undefined
  catchError _ _ = undefined
```

I'm getting another error:

`Functional dependencies conflict between instance declarations:
  instance MonadError String IO
    -- Defined at src/Video/Play/Base.hs:20:10
  instance [safe] MonadError GHC.IO.Exception.IOException IO
    -- Defined in ‘Control.Monad.Error.Class’`

I don't know how to force compiler to use `MonadError String IO` instace here.

- Should I assure GHC that my instance is better?
- Do I have a wrong environment setup? I'm using [ffmpeg-light](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ffmpeg-light) clone from [here](https://github.com/acowley/ffmpeg-light) and resolver `lts-7.2`. Host OS is Ubuntu.
- There is [commit](https://github.com/acowley/ffmpeg-light/commit/93f9c938e82b6ae1fda56e15c5047a1390431900) which replaces import of [Control.Monad.Error.Class](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.1/docs/Control-Monad-Error-Class.html) by [Control.Monad.Except](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.1/docs/Control-Monad-Except.html). But, [Control.Monad.Error.Class](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.1/docs/Control-Monad-Error-Class.html) is still used in [Codec.FFmpeg.Common](https://github.com/acowley/ffmpeg-light/blob/master/src/Codec/FFmpeg/Common.hsc). First time I thought it caused a problem. But it turns out that [Control.Monad.Except](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.1/docs/Control-Monad-Except.html) just re-exports [MonadError](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.1/docs/Control-Monad-Except.html#t:MonadError) class from [Control.Monad.Error.Class](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.1/docs/Control-Monad-Error-Class.html). So, it's not a problem.

Comment: Adding the instance will not work - the compiler is trying to tell you that. There is an existing instance for `IO` and the functional dependency means there can't be another one for `IO` even if the first parameter is different. You simply cannot run `openFile :: A -> IO B` - it must be a type with an `MonadError String` instance, such as `ExceptT String IO` (which also satisfies `MonadIO`). In the future, don't try to figure out how to 'force' the compiler to do anything - try to figure it what it's telling you (it's trying to help you!)

Comment: @user2407038 I changed my function to `openVideoFile :: String -> ExceptIO ()` where `ExceptIO` is `type ExceptIO = ExceptT String IO` and now it's working, thanks! Does functional dependency of `MonadError e m` say that if there is an instance where `m` is used already, then `m` cannot be used in another instance?